# Pedal Board Routing, using an A/B box in reverse

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal

I'm struggling to get my guitar pedal set up into a sane arrangement.

**I've tried the following signal path:**

```
                           -> Comp -> Chorus -> Crunch (A)
                          /                            \
Guitar  ->  Splitter   --<                              -> A/B Box -> Volume Pedal -> Phaser -> Delay -> AMP/CABS
                          \                            /
                           -> Big Muff Distortion ---> (B)
```

The failure is happening at the Splitter step. I've tried a dozen different (mono) Radio Shack splitters and couplers that I have and I can't get two signals to pass from the guitar to the Comp and Big Muff simultaneously, it only comes through one side of the splitter. I assume I'm using them in reverse, and there's some kind of restriction like a diode only allowing one-way signal. I want to replace the Splitter with something that makes sense, but I don't want to buy another A/B/Both box just to leave the setting on Both.

If you're wondering how I got in this state, I want to keep certain pedals on the back row and never touch them (Big Muff, Comp, Chorus). That's why I'm not running things in a straight line, I'd rather just hit the A/B switch.

I feel like I used some kind of pedal routing thing 10 years ago but I can't recall what it was.

Anything that helps fix this problem without adding much space (increased cost is expected) would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a Y-cable, which is what I assume you mean by "splitter" you lower the impedance of the load downstream. Lowering the impedance may affect the operation of the pedals.

I suggest that you first try reversing the order with the ABY box before the split and the splitter after. If that doesn't work, then I suggest getting a line selector like the BOSS LS-2.

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried 5 different Y splitters going into my volume pedal, using the AB box as intended, and I could only get a signal with one of the inputs connected. With both connected, something is being cancelled out. I'll look into line selectors, cheers!